# What network device do I need?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am trying to set up a home network like this:

Room 1 - Adsl modem & wireless router

Room 2 - Wifi signal is very weak. I also need 3 wired ethernet ports in here.

I have already laid a long ethernet cable from Room 1 to Room 2.  What do I need to do next?

Can I get an all in one device for room 2 that will seemlessly repeat/extend the wifi and also provide some ethernet ports?
(The simplest solution the better, ideally requiring very little setup)

Edit:
Modem and router have to be in Room 1 because of ADSL connection, but also it makes no difference as I want good wifi signal in both and same problem would exist in reverse.

Make of router is [Thomson TG582n](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/thomson/tg582n)

Comment: Why not have the router in room 2?

Comment: I would tend to assume that wi-fi needs to be available in both rooms. The possibility that I would be inclined to recommend is a second router with both wired and wifi connectivity, where you can configure it to _not_ do NAT or DHCP, leaving that functionality for the router in room 1. Recommendations, however, are off-topic, and this question may well be flagged for closure on that basis.

Comment: Please edit the question with the make/model number of the Wireless router you already have.  Also, please edit the question to say whether the possibility of putting the ASDL router in room 2 is an option.  I know my house only has phone ports in one spot.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage see edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *need* an “access point”. It’s very similar to a regular WiFi router, except it doesn’t route.

The basic setup steps would be somewhat like this:

- Connect to the device’s administration interface
- Change its IP address so it’s in the address range you use, but does not conflict with anything
- Set up the wireless network with the same SSID and security settings you already use on your router
- Connect one of the AP’s LAN ports to your local network

Clients will then be able to roam between the networks. Because all devices will be on the same broadcast domain, everything will just work<sup>TM</sup>.

While you only *need* an access point, a WiFi *router* can of course also do the job. It requires additional setup though:

- Do not connect it to your network, instead connect only the PC/laptop/whatever used to do the initial setup
- Connect to the device’s admin interface
- Change its IP address so it’s in the address range you use, but does not conflict with anything
- Disable DHCP
- (Optionally) Disable the Internet uplink (might turn off some warning LEDs)
- Set up the wireless network with the same SSID and security settings you already use on your router
- Connect one of the routers’s *LAN ports* (do *not* use the WAN port) to your local network

---

There is a tiny issue with all this: Some devices just can’t let go. They stay connected to a weak wireless network even when a known network with way superior reception is in range. Some routers/APs offer something called “roaming assist”. They basically just kick the client when its signal strength is too low, making the client reconsider its options. If your devices don’t have that, you may have to lower transmit power.

---

Most devices already come with an integrated 4-port switch. So your other three wired devices are also good to go. Just verify the specs before buying.

Comment: Me, the OP:  Thanks !  Works fine.  I found an old wireless modem/router, disabled WAN and DHCP, set the other things as you said and it does exactly what I want.  It even has a DHCP forwarding option to the main router :)

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want a device in the first room to have a controller with an AP (access point), and the second room to have another AP.  At my office, we use a wireless controller and several APs, with each AP power turned down so that end user devices must switch to the stronger AP in each room.  See https://www.securedgenetworks.com/blog/controller-vs-controllerless-wifi-whats-the-difference .

It's possible to have a wireless bridge, but that would give poor performance for your situation with only two rooms.  You've already done the right first step by laying an Ethernet cable.  Make sure it's physically secure and not going to be stepped on by people or chewed on by pets.  Running it above the ceiling is great, or in the ceiling/wall corner.

Comment: A managed wireless network is *completely* overkill for SOHO use.

Comment: Probably true, but recent WPA2 crack means that meshes are very insecure, having an Apple or Broadcom style wireless repeater is a bad solution for only two rooms because the signal in room 2 is bad, and having just a completely different SSID in room 2 isnt great either.  Maybe a wireless repeater in the hallway would work, except that he wants some ethernet ports in room 2.